# Can I give a default value like this to avoid null pointer exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Can I give variables default values such as this?

```
public class Laptop {
    // initializing variable to avoid null pointer exception?
    private String owner = "";

    public Laptop(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't avoid an NPE, if you invoke `new Laptop(null)`. The `""` is always overwritten in the constructor.

Comment: If you want `new Laptop(null)` to actually set the value to `""`, then use a ternary conditional operator in the constructor: `this.owner = (owner != null ? owner : "");`

Comment: If you want `owner` never to be null, add a null check wherever you assign it, e.g. `this.owner = Objects.requireNonNull(owner);`.

Comment: @AndyTurner But that doesn't follow OP's desire of "default value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private String owner = "";
```

Doing this is redundant because it's always overwritten in the constructor. The constructor would effectively be this:

```
public Laptop(String owner) {
    super();
    this.owner = "";
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

Clearly, the first assignment gets stomped straight away, so there's no point in doing it. Remove the initializer on the field.

If you want to be able to create a `Laptop` without an owner, you can provide a default value by overloading the constructor:

```
public Laptop() {
  this("");
}

public Laptop(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

Now you can invoke like:

```
Laptop owned = new Laptop("me"); // Will use the explicitly-provided owner "me".
Laptop unowned = new Laptop();   // Will use the default "".
```

If you never want `owner` to be null (I presume you're worried about later, when you use the result of `getOwner()`), add a null check wherever you assign `owner`:

```
this.owner = Objects.requireNonNull(owner);
```

This will fail with an [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) at the point of assignment, but that's a good place to fail if you never want a `null`-valued field: you can see exactly where that `null` came from, and fix that.

You could do something like what [Andreas suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997120/can-i-give-a-default-value-like-this-to-avoid-null-pointer-exception?noredirect=1#comment116686502_65997120):

```
this.owner = (owner != null ? owner : "");
```

but I would recommend against this: if you want `owner` to be `""`, that's the value you should pass into the constructor; passing in `null`, if that's not an allowed value, should be made clearly incorrect by throwing an exception. Passing in a value and having it coerced to some other value would feel surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you expect a `NullPointerException`? None of the code in your sample would cause an NPE, no matter if you initialise the attribute `owner` with the empty String, or not.

And when you call `new Laptop(null)` or `Laptop.setOwner(null)`, the attribute value will be overwritten, no matter which value it had before.

---

But yes, in general such an initialisation can be used to prevent an NPE, under the proper circumstance. Your code does not provides these circumstances …

Comment: This is not a full example you right, but what would happen if for example you make an API call, but owner is null and then you try to do something with owner, like just displaying it?

Comment: I'm new to java ahaha so I don't know if this is a real example

Comment: @Andry – You have to create an instance of `Laptop` first, and this would require a call to the constructor – that in turn will set `owner` to whatever the argument is. So yes, a call like `laptop.getOwner().isEmpty()` could cause an NPE – and because of the already mentioned reasons, the initialisation with the empty String would not make a difference here. But `System.out.println( laptop.getOwner()` would just write "null" to the console if `owner` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is fine but in order to guarantee that `getOwner()` will never return `null` you need to safeguard your set method like:

```
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner != null ? owner : "";
}
```

If on the other hand, setting `null` should be treated as an Exception because setting this property is considered violation of your workflow:

```
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    if (owner == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected owner found.");
    }
    this.owner = owner;
}
```